# Postfix Relay Servers behind ELB in AWS

Tags: postfix, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

I have three Relay Servers in a Cluster Sitting behind and ELB. The internal servers on the network connect to the ELB and send their SMTP traffic. The traffic is then routed to the Relay Server which is then sent to the destination Relay Servers. I've been able to confirm this functionality through TelNet, however when I changed the postfix configuration to point to the ELB in the main.cf, I am not able to connect to the Relay Servers. I'm not sure what the issue is: Below is my configuration in main.cf:

```
# RR: Mon Apr 29, 2013 => added 72.172.71.2/32 to support (LA) Duo VPN
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
myhostname = test.com
mydomain = test.com
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost



smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = yes
soft_bounce = no
strict_rfc821_envelopes = yes
local_header_rewrite_clients = permit_mynetworks
smtp_generic_maps = pcre:/etc/postfix/generic
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
broken_sasl_auth_clients = no
smtpd_sasl_application_name = smtpd
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtpd_sasl_local_domain =
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
#tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
#smtpd_tls_security_level = may
mailbox_size_limit = 102400000
message_size_limit = 51200000
queue_minfree = 76800000
smtpd_client_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unknown_client
smtpd_helo_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_invalid_hostname,
  reject_non_fqdn_hostname
smtpd_sender_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unlisted_sender,
  reject_non_fqdn_sender,
  reject_unknown_sender_domain
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  permit_sasl_authenticated,
  reject_unlisted_recipient,
  reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
  reject_unauth_destination,
  reject_unknown_recipient_domain
# check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/filtered_domains
smtpd_data_restrictions =
  permit_mynetworks,
  reject_unauth_pipelining,
  permit_sasl_authenticated
smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions =
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
  PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
  xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
#inet_protocols = all
postscreen_upstream_proxy_protocol = haproxy
```

master.cf:

```
    #
# Postfix master process configuration file.  For details on the format
# of the file, see the master(5) manual page (command: "man 5 master").
#
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (yes)   (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
submission inet n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_enforce_tls=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#smtps     inet  n       -       n       -       -       smtpd
#  -o smtpd_tls_wrappermode=yes
#  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#628      inet  n       -       n       -       -       qmqpd
pickup    fifo  n       -       n       60      1       pickup
cleanup   unix  n       -       n       -       0       cleanup
qmgr      fifo  n       -       n       300     1       qmgr
#qmgr     fifo  n       -       n       300     1       oqmgr
tlsmgr    unix  -       -       n       1000?   1       tlsmgr
rewrite   unix  -       -       n       -       -       trivial-rewrite
bounce    unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
defer     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
trace     unix  -       -       n       -       0       bounce
verify    unix  -       -       n       -       1       verify
flush     unix  n       -       n       1000?   0       flush
proxymap  unix  -       -       n       -       -       proxymap
smtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
# When relaying mail as backup MX, disable fallback_relay to avoid MX loops
relay     unix  -       -       n       -       -       smtp
        -o fallback_relay=
#       -o smtp_helo_timeout=5 -o smtp_connect_timeout=5
showq     unix  n       -       n       -       -       showq
error     unix  -       -       n       -       -       error
discard   unix  -       -       n       -       -       discard
local     unix  -       n       n       -       -       local
virtual   unix  -       n       n       -       -       virtual
lmtp      unix  -       -       n       -       -       lmtp
anvil     unix  -       -       n       -       1       anvil
scache    unix  -       -       n       -       1       scache
#
# ====================================================================
# Interfaces to non-Postfix software. Be sure to examine the manual
# pages of the non-Postfix software to find out what options it wants.
#
# Many of the following services use the Postfix pipe(8) delivery
# agent.  See the pipe(8) man page for information about ${recipient}
# and other message envelope options.
# ====================================================================
#
# maildrop. See the Postfix MAILDROP_README file for details.
# Also specify in main.cf: maildrop_destination_recipient_limit=1
#
maildrop  unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=DRhu user=vmail argv=/usr/local/bin/maildrop -d ${recipient}
#
# The Cyrus deliver program has changed incompatibly, multiple times.
#
old-cyrus unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=R user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -m ${extension} ${user}
# Cyrus 2.1.5 (Amos Gouaux)
# Also specify in main.cf: cyrus_destination_recipient_limit=1
cyrus     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  user=cyrus argv=/usr/lib/cyrus-imapd/deliver -e -r ${sender} -m ${extension} ${user}
#
# See the Postfix UUCP_README file for configuration details.
#
uucp      unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fqhu user=uucp argv=uux -r -n -z -a$sender - $nexthop!rmail ($recipient)
#
# Other external delivery methods.
#
ifmail    unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=F user=ftn argv=/usr/lib/ifmail/ifmail -r $nexthop ($recipient)
bsmtp     unix  -       n       n       -       -       pipe
  flags=Fq. user=foo argv=/usr/local/sbin/bsmtp -f $sender $nexthop $recipient
```

This is what I see in the relay server maillog:

```
AED0D6093E: message-id=<20170420163035.AED0D6093E<test.com>
```

And on the mail client it's saying undeliverable. Please let me know if anyone understands what might be going on.

Comment: You appear to have used the term "relay server" to mean two different things.  *"The traffic is then routed to the Relay Server which is then sent to the destination Relay Servers."*  Um... what?  *"This is what I see in the relay server maillog"*  Which relay server are we talking about?  *"And on the mail client it's saying undeliverable"* "It's saying?"  Who is "it" and what exactly does "it" say?  Is this a bounce message? And if so, from where and how did the message get delivered back to the client? I believe the question needs some clarification and additional detail.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make Postfix see client IP addresses behind an NLB, by checking "Preserve client IP addresses" in the [target group attributes](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/network/load-balancer-target-groups.html#target-group-attributes). No need to use HAproxy or activate proxy protocol v2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to using postfix behind ELB you must using postscreen and haproxy to make it works. Add the following line to the configuration :
main.cf :

```
postscreen_upstream_proxy_protocol = haproxy
```

master.cf:

```
smtp  inet  n  —  —  —  1  postscreen
smtpd pass  —  —  —  —  —  smtpd
```

Also you need to change the configuration o fELB, here is the link for set ELB for postfix : https://medium.com/@signalnine/preserving-source-ip-running-postfix-behind-amazon-elastic-load-balancer-2a241b69681a